# jhipster - how to master data management and microservices communications?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, apache-kafka, jhipster, microservices

I'm working on a project using jHipster and microservices architecture , I'm new to this technology but, i'm really concerned about performance and app architecture.

So my use case is having a gateway and one other microservice, 
the gateway is responsible for managing all user related data like favorites restaurants ... , and the other microservice is responsible for restaurants data management, including crud and search operations.

So my question is if I have an endpoint for adding a new favorite restaurant or selecting all favorite restaurant for a specific user, what approche i will follow

PS: I'm using mongoDB for storing data

1 - save only the ids of the restaurants in my user favorite document :

```
pros : 
     - they will be no master data management if a restaurant is 
      updated.
cons : 
     - there will be a tied coupling between microservices because
      requesting favorite restaurant will depend on restaurant microservice 
     - performance impact requesting list of restaurants in every 
       favorite restaurant request
```

2 - save favorite restaurants with embed documents of restaurants

```
pros: 
     - there will be no tied coupling between microservices
     - better performance 
cons
     - we need master data management for updating data 
     - what to do if restaurant microservice is down when inserting a new favorite restaurant?
```

So what to choose and is there a better solution or better architecture? 
Another question how can I use the benefits of kafka in my use case?

Ps: keep in mind that I might face a large trafic.

Comment: Great question. I'm not sure how to restrict a user to see only the entries generated by themselves.

Example: Blog Microservice:
* User see only the blogs that they have created/own.
* Admin can see each and every Blog entries.
I want to do something like shown in this Jhipster video tutorial for monolithic application:
https://youtu.be/XRREt1KB4Y8?t=7m47s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ps: keep in mind that i might face a large trafic .

I will base my answer on this.

First of all, you should move `Favorite Restaurants` to a dedicated microservice and let the API Gateway do routing and cross concerns only (authentication, authorization, SSL termination etc).

Second, you could split the concerns in Read and Write concerns in the Favorite Restaurants bounded context - use CQRS.

So, adding/removing a favorite restaurant could be handled by a microservice that publishes the `FavoriteRestaurantAdded(UserId, RestaurantId)` and `FavoriteRestaurantRemoved(UserId, RestaurantId)` domain events.

Another microservice could be responsible with maintaining the list of favorite restaurants for each user in a fully denormalized way: the list contains the ID and the title of the Restaurant (and other needed properties) - a Read model in CQRS. The microservice is subscribed to Restaurant related domain events like `RestaurantRenamed` or `RestaurantRemoved` and updates the Favorite restaurants accordingly (for example, it removes the Favorite restaurant when the `RestaurantRemoved` event is received). This microservice can be made as fast as possible (i.e. by using sharding or indexes and by not using any *joins*) and can be scaled independently.

On important note, the Read microservice is eventually consistent with the other microservices (the Favorite restaurant adding/removing microservice and Restaurant management microservice). You should keep this in mind when you design the UI; or, you could make the API Gateway to wait for the Read model to be updated.

This architecture is more complex but it gives you better separation of concerns and as fast-as-light, linear-scalable queries.